Error '"QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error.', then Visual Studio no longer uses 'Additional Include Directories'
I have a C++ QT desktop application built with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.10.5 and Qt 6.7.2.
After making some changes to images used by the application, it started returning this build error:

"QtRunWork" task returned false but did not log an error.

As per usual when obscure errors appear out of nowhere, I restarted Visual Studio and re-loaded the project. Rather than fixing the problem, it became much worse. Every Qt class name was now considered undefined. Every #include line that included a Qt header file was underlined in red and gave an error message indicating that the source file does not exist.
I found that it wasn't just Qt header files that it no longer recognized the existence of. It would no longer recognize any header files that were in any of the project's "Additional Include Directories". It would only recognize header files in the project's directory, or that were actually included in the project's list of headers.
I tried reverting my source files and project files to a previous version, uninstalled and reinstalled VS, and remade the project from scratch. The problem kept re-appearing.

We need a [mre]. As per usual when obscure errors appear out of nowhere, - this is not true. You have made wrong changes in the code.

@3CxEZiVlQ Yes, I agree. I posted this, not to get an answer from the community, but just so I could post the solution I eventually discovered, in case others run into this problem.

After wrestling with this for hours I found the answer and wanted to post it here in case anyone else runs into this.
The problem occurred when I deleted an image used in my application, and renamed a different image to the same filename as the one I deleted. The deleted image had been included as a resource in the project's .qrc file. Apparently deleting and replacing that image without first removing it from the .qrc file is what caused the problem to begin.
I remade my project from scratch, and as I incrementally re-added my source files it continued to build correctly until I re-added that .qrc file. At that point it once again gave me the "QtRunWork" error. I exited Visual Studio, then restarted it and re-loaded the project, and sure enough it once again would not recognize any headers located in the "Additional Include Directories".
At that point it didn't help when I removed and then replaced the .qrc file. Somehow having restarted Visual Studio while the .qrc file was in that state messed something up so that it could no longer find files in the Additional Include Directories.
The solution that worked for me was to create a new Qt project, re-add my source files, but start with a fresh .qrc file rather than re-adding my old one to the project.
